# Gulp error with yeoman webapp generator using gulp-jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, yeoman, gulp

I have a hard time integrating jade with yeoman's gulp webapp generator.
The watch task is already working as expected but once I try to build the project I get the following error:

```
stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
TypeError: path must be a string
```

I assume it is because I changed the html task to `return gulp.src('.tmp/*.html')` (*it was `'app/*.html'` originally, which runs without an error but of course ignores my jade templates*).

### My gulpfile:

```
'use strict';
// generated on 2014-04-17 using generator-gulp-webapp 0.0.7

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    jade = require('gulp-jade');

// load plugins
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/styles/main.sass')
        .pipe($.rubySass({
            style: 'expanded',
            compass: true,
            loadPath: 'app/bower_components'
        }))
        .pipe($.autoprefixer('> 5%', 'last 3 versions', 'ff >= 20', 'ie 9'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'))
        .pipe($.size());
});

gulp.task('templates', function() {
    var YOUR_LOCALS = {};

    return gulp.src('app/*.jade')
        .pipe(jade({
            locals: YOUR_LOCALS,
            pretty: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp'))
        .pipe($.size());
});

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/scripts/**/*.js')
        .pipe($.jshint())
        .pipe($.jshint.reporter($.jshintStylish))
        .pipe($.size());
});

gulp.task('html', ['templates', 'styles', 'scripts'], function () {
    var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js');
    var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css');

    return gulp.src('.tmp/*.html')
        .pipe($.useref.assets())
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe($.uglify())
        .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
        .pipe(cssFilter)
        .pipe($.csso())
        .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
        .pipe($.useref.restore())
        .pipe($.useref())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
        .pipe($.size());
});

gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/images/**/*')
        .pipe($.cache($.imagemin({
            optimizationLevel: 3,
            progressive: true,
            interlaced: true
        })))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
        .pipe($.size());
});

gulp.task('fonts', function () {
    return $.bowerFiles()
        .pipe($.filter('**/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff}'))
        .pipe($.flatten())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles/fonts'))
        .pipe($.size());
});

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return gulp.src(['.tmp', 'dist'], { read: false }).pipe($.clean());
});

gulp.task('build', ['html', 'images', 'fonts']);

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
    gulp.start('build');
});

gulp.task('connect', function () {
    var connect = require('connect');
    var app = connect()
        .use(require('connect-livereload')({ port: 35729 }))
        .use(connect.static('app'))
        .use(connect.static('.tmp'))
        .use(connect.directory('app'));

    require('http').createServer(app)
        .listen(9000)
        .on('listening', function () {
            console.log('Started connect web server on http://localhost:9000');
        });
});

gulp.task('serve', ['connect', 'styles', 'templates'], function () {
    require('opn')('http://localhost:9000');
});

// inject bower components
gulp.task('wiredep', function () {
    var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;

    gulp.src('app/styles/*.sass')
        .pipe(wiredep({
            directory: 'app/bower_components'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/styles'));

    gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(wiredep({
            directory: 'app/bower_components'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['connect', 'serve'], function () {
    var server = $.livereload();

    // watch for changes

    gulp.watch([
        'app/*.html',
        'app/**/*.jade',
        '.tmp/styles/**/*.css',
        'app/scripts/**/*.js',
        'app/images/**/*'
    ]).on('change', function (file) {
        server.changed(file.path);
    });

    gulp.watch('app/**/*.jade', ['templates']);
    gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.sass', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('app/scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('app/images/**/*', ['images']);
    gulp.watch('bower.json', ['wiredep']);
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are using `gulp-load-plugins`, so you can remove the `var jade = require('gulp-jade');` and replace `jade()` references below with `$.jade()`.

Comment: The error `TypeError: path must be a string` is very ambiguous. It basically means useref could not locate a source file.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the error came from gulp-useref having problems with my build blocks.
Changing all blocks to use `{app,.tmp}` as it's search path fixed the behaviour, e.g.:

```
// build:js({app,.tmp}) scripts/vendor/modernizr.js 
script(src='bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js')
// endbuild
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.

To fix your `wiredep` task, add this after the `gulp.src('app/*.html')` block:

```
gulp.src('app/*.jade')
    .pipe(wiredep({
        directory: 'app/bower_components'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
```

This will update the `// bower:js` ... `// endbower` blocks in your `.jade` files when your `bower.json` changes, triggered by the watch:

```
gulp.watch('bower.json', ['wiredep']);
```

at the end of your gulpfile.

Eg.

When I add `"jquery": "~1.11.0"` as a dependencies in my `bower.json` (and save).

In my `/app/layout.jade` file, this:

```
body
    // bower:js
    // endbower
```

Gets replaced with:

```
body
    // bower:js
    script(src='bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js')
    // endbower
```

---

If you want to use `build:js` without adding `({app,.tmp})` to all of your blocks, in your `html` task, add both `app` and `.tmp` to the source.

Your `.js` and `.css` are in the `app` directory, so when you changed the source to `.tmp/*.html` instead of `app/*.html`, your two $.filters didn't find any files.

To work around this, make the `gulp.src()` an array containing both paths.

Replace:

```
gulp.task('html', ['templates', 'styles', 'scripts'], function () {
    var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js');
    var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css');

    return gulp.src('.tmp/*.html')
    ...
```

With:

```
gulp.task('html', ['templates', 'styles', 'scripts'], function () {
    var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js');
    var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css');

    return gulp.src(['app/*.html', '.tmp/*.html'])
    ...
```

Comment: Coming from Grunt Gulp is a pretty different system but thanks to you, i am getting it all (also thank you for your hints in the comments).

Comment: I am sorry, but using your method I still get the error. Maybe it is due to my CSS is also in the .tmp folder? My CSS block looks as follows: `// build:css styles/main.css
 link(rel='stylesheet', href='styles/main.css')
 // endbuild `

I have also tried adding (.tmp) and (app) to all blocks or leaving it out…

Comment: I only started using it today myself. I built mine using yeoman generator 0.0.8 (yours is 0.0.7). I noticed there were a few differences, one in particular is the `.scss` vs `.sass` extension. Mine uses `main.scss`.

Comment: Try running `npm install -g generator-gulp-webapp` and `yo gulp-webapp` again to install the latest version and compare the two `gulpfile.js` files.

Comment: If you are wondering why your jshint-stylish isn't working, try replacing `$.jshintStylish` with `require('jshint-stylish')` in your `scripts` task. I submitted a PR to Yeoman to fix it in newer versions.

Comment: I changed the extension to .sass manually, because I use the SASS syntax, but this should not be the reason for the error. Also it seems the yeoman team did not change much since 0.0.7 (I am certain the update would not change my situation). Maybe you could post some parts from your gulpfile and your build blocks?

Comment: Well for the time being I unchecked your answer as the right one, because I still have to use ({app,.tmp}) in my build blocks.